# CreateProcessAsUser failing with 1349 :The type of the token is inappropriate for its attempted use

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-authentication, windows-security, createprocessasuser

Creating a token using `OpenThreadToken()` and then passing it to `CreateProcessAsUser` is failing with:

> 1349:The type of the token is inappropriate for its attempted use.

It is successful on one machine but failing on other win2008r2.

The `DesiredAccess` that is passed to `OpenThreadToken` is:
`TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE|TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY`

Comment: Does OpenThreadToken succeed? If not what is the result of GetLastError?

Comment: Yes , the OpenThreadToken is succedding .

Answer (score 1):

exist 2 [TOKEN_TYPE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379633(v=vs.85).aspx) - `TokenPrimary` and `TokenImpersonation` . [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) accept only `TokenPrimary`. from another side, thread if have token - always have `TokenImpersonation` token type. so token returned by [OpenThreadToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379296(v=vs.85).aspx) is `TokenImpersonation` you need call [`DuplicateTokenEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617(v=vs.85).aspx)`(.., TokenPrimary, );` and pass this new token to `CreateProcessAsUser`

--- EDIT ---

really begin from Windows 7 we can use and `TokenImpersonation` as parameter to `CreateProcessAsUser` although in MSDN written about primary token. but in xp/2003 used another code for `CreateProcessAsUser` - direct called `NtSetInformationProcess(,ProcessAccessToken,);` -> `PspSetPrimaryToken` -> `PspAssignPrimaryToken` -> `STATUS_BAD_TOKEN_TYPE`

Comment: But i am seeing this issue on only one machine , it is passing on other machine .Is there any registry entry that may creating the problem on  that machine .

Comment: any registry entry here unrelated. token returned by OpenThreadToken must not work with CreateProcessAsUser anywhere (may be xp only, where another implementation of CreateProcessAsUser - first create process than try assign token to it). and you not show self code

Comment: is there any other way other than DuplicateTokenEx () to convert a impersonation token into primary token ?

Comment: @RbMm Is there an working code example for this?

Comment: @T.s.Arun - example for what ?

Comment: For PspSetPrimaryToken. I have used NtSetInformationProcess to assign token for the suspended process. But the suspended process crashes when resumed, Not right away, but when I tried to fetch the process token and print its privileges it crashed. I haven't tried using PspSetPrimaryToken. So it would be helpful if there is an example to refer to. @RbMm

Answer (score 0):

The target thread is impersonating at the time of the call, so you're getting the wrong token.  Using [OpenProcessToken()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of [OpenThreadToken()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379296(v=vs.85).aspx) should resolve the problem.  If for some reason you only have the thread ID and not the process ID, [GetProcessIdOfThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683216(v=vs.85).aspx) will bridge the gap.

Alternatively, if you had some reason for wanting to use the impersonation token you would have to use [DuplicateTokenEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert it into a primary token.  But this is unlikely to be what you want to do, because it introduces a race condition, since you would typically have no way to know when the target thread is impersonating the right user.  Also, it will not work at all if the thread turns out to be impersonating at the anonymous level.

(This race condition is probably also why it seems to be working on some machines but not others, although it might also be that the impersonation takes place only on certain Windows versions.)